# Using one instance webview for multi page

Tags: android

I want to paging a web's content in an android application. For example, i use Flipview to display each page of web content, and i don't know how to using the same webview which i created, loaded url to display on each flipview page.

Anyone as any suggest for me !

Thanks for all suggestions !

Comment: Multi page is from the same web URL? Or multi page means you have different layouts with WebView?

Comment: Hi pareshMayani, it mean multi page is from the same web URL

Answer (score 0):

use webview.cangoback() property.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

for more details please visit. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this's not what i need :). I mean, i have a webview loaded with an url, and i want to use this webpage for multi time for each flipview page :).